# Зависает вызов stat

Tags: linux, nfs

Всем здраствуйте. Монтирую nfs на машину. Спустя какое-то время сервер nfs умирает, т.е. хост становиться недоступен. Дергаю `stat` на смонтированную директорию и он виснет... Как нужно смонтировать nfs, что бы stat не зависал, а отвался через некоторое время.
Опции монтирования nfs: `rw,intr,soft,timeo=600,acregmax=30,acdirmax=30,retrans=5,retry=2`

Comment: а что на серверной части? какой линк?